# Unable to return items under folder using CAML

Tags: caml-query

I have a folder in the default "Images" library under my site, called Menu Icons:

/PublishingImages/Menu Icons

I want to retrieve only the images under this folder, and not all images under the root as well, so I thought something like this would work (based on Google searches):

```
<View>
     <Where>
         <Contains>
             <FieldRef Name="FileRef" />
             <Value>/PublishingImages/Mega Menu</Value>
         </Contains>
     </Where>
</View>
```

But this brings back all images under /PublishingImages.

If I then view the field values for each, I can see FileRef, /PublishingImages/ for all but one, the one I want located under /Menu Icons.

This looks right?

Comment: Could you not use <Eq> instead of <Contains>?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your code, I think you are using the Client Object Model. There is a property in the Query object `FolderServerRelativeUrl` which you can use.

If you are using the client object model:

.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.folderserverrelativeurl.aspx
`query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/PublishingImages/Mega Menu";`

JS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee549054(v=office.14).aspx
`query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl("/PublishingImages/Mega Menu");`

Also have a look at this excellent blog about working with Client Object Model Caml Queries in detail:
http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/caml-and-the-client-object-model/

If you are using the Server Object Model, there is a property: `SPQuery.Folder`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.folder.aspx

Comment: using the OM from within C#, so this worked. thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
    `<View Scope="Recursive">`
    `<Query>.....`
    `</View>`
This should solve your problem.

Comment: This, for some reason didn't work ?: but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although using the `FolderServerRelativeUrl` property of the `Query` object on the client side, or the `Folder` property of the `SPQuery` object on the server side as written in the answer by @VardhamanDeshpande should work in your case (I mean, using the OM from C#), there might be cases, when you should filter the results in the CAML-query itself, like when creating a custom view for a document library. For example, we had a requirement to create a view that applies different filter criteria on the root folder level, as on the subfolder level.

We could achieve that via a CAML-query like that:

```
<Eq>
  <FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' />
  <Value Type='Text'>/YourSite/SubWeb/DocLib/Folder</Value>
</Eq>
```

- It is important to ensure that you use the server (and not site!) relative URL of the folder, beginning with a slash. If you use a wrong folder path (that does not exist, or does not belong to a folder within the list you want to filter), the items in the list won't be filtered at all.
- You should use `Eq` instead of `Contains`, as suggested by @BlueBird.
- Last but not least, you should specify the filter value type as `Text` (see: `<Value Type='Text'>`). Without that we had not received any results.